# Query shows no results when searching for dates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
select 
  order_slip,
  product_name,
  month 
from orders 
where month >= 09/03/2015 
and month <= 09/09/2015
```

This is my query and it has no result. I have tried this query also:

```
select 
  order_slip,
  product_name,
  month from orders 
 where month between date(09/03/2015) and date(09/09/2015)
```

but it returns more than the date 09/09/09

Comment: its a good practice to always use str_to_date function and get local values converted to date format.  `str_to_date('09/03/2015','%d/%m/%Y')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute something like this:

```
select order_slip,product_name,month from orders where month between '09/03/2015' and '09/09/2015'
```

The column month has to be Date type.

Comment: Thank you guys :) my date is in varchar type but it works :) Thanks dude appreciate your help thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

`09/03/2015` is interpreted as "9 divided by 3 divided 2015" (which is 0.001488...).  This is obviously not what you want.

Dates need to be *quoted* as strings.  They also need to be in the correct format.  If you are using a `DATE` or `DATETIME` field, then you need to use `2015-09-03`.

```
select 
  order_slip,
  product_name,
  month 
from orders 
where month >= '2015-09-03' 
and month <= '2015-09-09'
```

Comment: could `where MONTH(month) between '03' and '09'` work assuming `month` column holds the entire date?

Comment: `03` and `09` are not the months in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TO_DATE() function.

If you want to know more about this command please access throught this link.
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Answer (score 0):

The dates are in quotes i.e '2015-09-15' and YYYY-MM-DD format.

Try:

```
select order_slip, product_ name,month 
from orders 
where month >= '2015-09-03' 
and month <= '2015-09-09'
```